# IntelliJ : how to verify log4j2.xml is on the classpath?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, log4j2, spring-initializr

I'm working on a spring boot/maven project that I created with SpringIntializr. If I add all the necessary dependencies to my pom, and if I add my log4j2.xml to MyApp/src/main/resources,
and if after a build I see my log4j2.xml file in MyApp/target/classes, does that mean that the log4j config has been successfully added to the classpath?

I asked a more comprehensive question [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70219817/intellij-log4j-does-not-output-log-file?noredirect=1#comment124131041_70219817) but thought this issue might merit a standalone question

Comment: When you run the app, IDE prints the command line which includes the classpath. If you see this directory in the command line classpath, then it's there.

Answer (score 0):

Basically yes, what gets to the classes, later on, gets handled by the spring-boot maven plugin and should be available in the artifact that you build.
At this point it doesn't really matter whether it was originally in the `src/main/resources` folder or not.

Having said that, log4j2 is not used by spring boot by default (it uses logback), so you should set it up
For such a setup see [this example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-logging#log4j2-configuration-logging)

Comment: that has the same problem...I get the log output in the main spring log, but the file defined in the log4j2.xml file is not created

Comment: Check the resulting artifact (jar). Does it have lo4j2.xml packed inside? Does it have a log4j2 starter does it have other starters of logging in the BOOT-INF/lib folder?